# New Xcode deveopment computer certificate issues

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, certificate

I have installed the latest Xcode onto a new iMac for a company I just started working for. Their iOS development is currently being done on another computer off-site by a third party. Using the same developer account, how can I get this computer the proper certificate without de-activating the other machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other machine will have the Development key in the Keychain Access.. you need to have those exported to you in .p12 format and the corresponding certificate and install them on your mac..then just download the certificate from the dev center..and you will be ready to develop and deploy with existing provisioning profiles..

**Note the key has to be the private key..not the public one**

Comment: Thanks, I will request that from them!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same developer account, log into `http://developer.apple.com` with that account's credentials and navigate to iOS Provisioning Profile -> Certificates.  There you will see a button to download your certificate.

Comment: Yeah, I have reloaded the certificate, however, I'm still getting the the "The identity XXXXXXXXXXXX doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain". Can I get these keys by having the other developer export them and send them over to me?